# doubts run c++ code using R

Tags: c++, r, vector

I am trying to work with c++ code using R, but I can not use objects from other libraries

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int fun(int x, int n) {
   for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
    x=x+n;
   }
   return x;
}
```

R read correctly this simple code , so what do I need to reed vectors?

Thanks

Comment: See the code in the section Vector Input Scalar Output of this page: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html#rcpp-sugar